# jQuery find() function current element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move strings from name attributes to the src of each img.
I'm using jQuery to do this:

```
$("#one").find("img").attr("src",$(this).attr("name");
```

Now the problem is that $(this) is not the current manipulated element. So how do I get the current element that find() has found?

Comment: Where's the `name` coming from? the `#one` or the `img`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`attr` method accepts a function, within the context of this function, `this` refers to the current element:

```
$("#one").find("img").attr("src", function(){
    return this.name
});
```

Comment: Oh yes of course. I thought it would be possible without creating a local function but it works, the img is now visible :)
Thanks!

Comment: @Lahaye Note: `.attr` is just going to pick the first image.. it will not update thru all the image that the find going to return. _Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements_

Comment: @Vega That's not the case with `attr`'s function.